# Django/Python - how to crawl html and change text and send as html email

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send html emails to users and i have one html template.

html content starts with:

```
Dear XYZ, ..
```

how is it possible to change `XYZ` with users name that i am sending this mail to? how can i crawl the html and change that name and do this?:

```
subject, from_email, to = 'subject', 'test@gmail.com', 'email'
html_content = render_to_string('the_template.html', {'varname':'value'}) # ...
text_content = strip_tags(html_content) 
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

this would save me a month!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your template should have

```
Dear {{name}}
```

as part of it and when you render instead of using

```
html_content = render_to_string('the_template.html', {'varname':'value'})
```

use

```
html_content = render_to_string('the_template.html', {'name':<whatever name you want>})
```

if you're referring to it from the `request` object, you can use

```
Dear {{request.user.first_name}} {{request.user.last_name}}
```

instead.

Comment: @doniyor I would highly appreciate it if you could clickety-clack that check mark after 15 minutes if it solved your problem

Comment: oh sure, dude! i am waiting for the time :)

Comment: You can get a bit more flexibility with [`django-templated-email`](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, thanks but i dont like installing some foreign apps, better if i do it, then i understand why and what i write every line of code.

Comment: Its open source, so you can read the code and figure out what its doing. :)